# Cancelling long running tasks in case of a system crash and rolling back

Tags: c#, async-await

I would like to start varying number of tasks to do some background work inside an APIController (WebAPI self-hosted OWIN). Basically:

1. Get the request from the client (vi HTTP POST) and return as soon as
   possible (with a 200/202 status code) without waiting the long
   running task to complete (client should be waited on that long
   running task.
2. Publish the results of that operation will be published by using a
   different channel (ex: a message queue).

First of all, I am planning to ktrack these tasks instead of completely fire and forget approach. I would like to keep these tasks in a collection.

1. Add after creation just before starting the task.
2. Remove after RanToCompletion or any kind of fault/cancel. Error
   handling will be done in an exception handler.

Second - critical point - is crash recovery. I play with the data(base) within these tasks and in case of a system crash (probably uncaught exception or not a crash but some possible exception on the execution path) I would like to some kind of rollback to bring the system to a consistent state. My first approach was passing the same cancellation token to all these tasks and waiting calling `Cancel` on that common `CancellationTokenSource` and handling the `OperationCanceledException`. In the handler of `OperationCanceledException` I can do some housekeeping and everything will be fine.

It's a little bit complicated for me and seems to be hard to make solid. I am trying to find a solution to that problem - if possible - without using any third party service like [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/). It may be a broad topic, but my priority is crash recovery and bringing the system to a consistent state.

Comment: The way to rollback changes in a database on failure is called a transaction. Open a transaction shared by all three tasks and roll it back if any of them fails.

Comment: if you are updated data in the database, perhaps it might be worthwhile creating a temporary table first, which initially contains the original data which is then updated as the job continues. At the end, once all data has been processed within the temp table (assuming there has been no error condition), you then update the rows in the live database in a transaction. If there is an error, you can then do a rollback if needed.

Comment: Good points, but we keep a flag in the db which shows the status of the ongoing task(s). Different from a transaction its like a semaphore in terms concurrency. Not a very good approach I think and also one of the biggest causes of this problem. That's why I am looking for something better. May be I am overlooking alternatives, not sure.

Comment: You'r trying to reinvent the wheel. The other commentors mentioned before what you need to achieve your mentioned behaviour. Transactions are different because of a need for a commit of the whole transaction at the end. Otherwhise you can drop the transaction if failures happened. Don't try to reinvent something already working and properly done. Just a tip of myself, facing sometimes such situations.

Comment: Any advice on non-db operations during the housekeeping?